# Solving $T(n)=2T(n/2) + n \lg n$ , For ex: Counting inversions implemented with full mergesort

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation, recursion, master-theorem, divide-and-conquer

How to solve the recurrence equation $T(n)=2T(n/2) + n \lg n$

For ex: I implemented "Counting inversions" with a full mergesort instead of just using merge part, So the outer complexity will be **$n \lg n$.**

Also, What is the  $O$(complexity) of above ?

Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition (p.95) has an example of how to solve the a similar recurrence $T(n)= 3T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + n  \log(n)$  using master theorem by showing $f(n)$ is polynomially larger than $n^{\log_b a}$. But I am not sure about this one.

Comment: No, It might be possible to solve using Master Theorem.

Comment: Yes, and [this answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2823/9550) to the question I linked covers the Master Theorem, including your example, which is the case $a=b=2$, $k=1$. (I mean case 2 of the specific way that that answer phrases the theorem; other sources may present the cases in a different order and/or have different cases.)

Comment: I don't see k = 1 case, also can you check edited question.
Can you edit your answer to include $T(n)=2T(n/2) + n \lg n$
  in http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2823/9550

Comment: $T(n)=aT(n/b) + n^{\log_b a} \log^k n$ with $a=b=2$, $k=1$, gives exactly $T(n)=2T(n/2)+n\log n$.

Comment: Hence, as David said, in this case you'll have $T(n)=\Theta(n\lg^2n)$.